# .headerにhoverした際、#pankuzuを非表示にしたい

Tags: javascript

下記のサイトを参考にして、`<div class="header">`にhoverした際、`<div id="pankuzu">`が非表示になるように設定したのですが、全く反応しませんでした。

何が原因か、ご教示いただけますでしょうか。

参考にしたサイト：
[show, hide (マウスオーバーで表示・非表示を切り替える)](http://yurubu.org/jquery%E3%82%BC%E3%83%AD%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-02-show-hide/293/)

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <div class="header">ヘッダー内容</div>
    <div id="pankuzu">
        <ul>
            <li>パンくずの内容</li>
            <li>パンくずの内容</li>
            <li>パンくずの内容</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

**HEAD内のscript記述**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.header').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#pankuzu').hide();
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('#pankuzu').show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: 私の環境だと問題なく動いているようです。https://fiddle.jshell.net/em630sou/ 　確認した環境（ブラウザ等）追記していただき、JSエラーなどが出ていないかなど確認をお願いします

Comment: 質問とそれますが、個人的には CSS だけで以下のように書くのが楽で良いと思います。
「.header:hover+#pankuzu {display:none}」